# Javers - Conversion from SetChange to ListChange

Tags: java, javers

I have `NodeDto` which has a property `Set<DeviceDto>`. I am able to track the changes for these DTO in javers tables but we are not able see which nested objects have changed.

The because of Set, the **fragment** column value in jv_global_id table will be stored like - `siteDto/nodes/0/devices/37066f24d805da700a7465e4b9575147.`

I want to have index wise like below. It helps to see which nested objects have changed -

```
siteDto/nodes/0/devices/3
siteDto/nodes/0/devices/3/powerPorts/0
```

How to convert **SetChange** to **ListChange** in javers?. Could you please help me?

Comment: You can't have indexes in Set, change `Set<DeviceDto>` to `List<DeviceDto>`

Comment: I cannot change set to list. I tried by adding @Value and @Entity. results won't come  like ```siteDto/nodes/0/devices/3```. Is any other way to do it ?

Comment: You cannot change Set to List in your own class?

Comment: I need Set there. So I cannot change it..

Comment: In programming and also in math, Sets are unordered, by definition

Comment: I have created new DTO for converting from set to list. This is enough for my requirement. Thanks @BartekWalacik for the responding for my queries